# Use 3 prong microwave on 2 wire ungrounded outlet?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have a dedicated, ungrounded 15A outlet. Can I use a microwave with a 3 prong plug on it if I install an AFCI/GFCI combo outlet? Or do I need to also ground the outlet?

The microwave owners manual says the outlet must be at least 15A.

Comment: Grounding is for safety, so "can I use" is going to be a little subjective.  The microwave doesn't need a ground to function.

Comment: You don't need an AFCI. I like to stack up two or three of those 3-to-2 adapters, you know, to be sure. :P

Comment: Does code allow it? The GFCI would protect the user, but not necessarily the equipment?

Comment: Does the microwave's labeling or instructions say anything about a grounded outlet or groundless GFCI?  It is a Code violation to install any equipment contrary to the labeling and instructions under which it was listed.  To answer your question @user1594257 ...listing is the result of testing, and the testing was done only for the uses described in the labeling and instructions.

Answer (score -1):

The capacitor of a microwave oven, stores voltage of over 2,000, even when plugged out; I would not take a chance with ungrounding it;;;

Comment: Since the microwave _is_ ungrounded when you unplug it, what do you do with the microwave when you need to move it? Do you call in an electrician? The bomb squad? This seems more like irrational scare tactics than practical advice. Please [edit] your answer to expand on this.

Comment: This is relevant to *repair* of microwave ovens. I don't think it is relevant to consumer usage.